# Hide a div on completion of password

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a basic input box that once a password is entered, it shows a div. This works fine but I would also like the password input box to disappear. I thought I could just use the same code and change the toggle to hide but the div hides as soon as a letter is pressed.

Question - how do I get it to hide once the password is complete (and correct).

I think I need in if statement saying that 'if the password matches then hide the div' but I'm not sure...

I would also like to put a 1sec delay on hiding the input div too. This is done with the .delay function isn't it?

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
//this shows the div
$(document).ready(function() {
  'use strict';
  $('#ae').on('keyup', function() {
    $('#ae-form').toggle(this.value.trim().toLowerCase() == 'allerganemployee');
  });
});

//this needs to hide the input box  
$(document).ready(function() {
  'use strict';
  $('#ae').on('keyup', function() {
    $('#ae-input').hide(this.value.trim().toLowerCase() == 'allerganemployee');
  });
});
```

```css
#ae-form {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="allergan box">
  <h2>Registration for Employees</h2>
  <div id="ae-input">
    <p>Please enter your password</p>
    <input type="password" id="ae" />
  </div>
  <div id="ae-form">
    This is the form
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: password matches to which?

Comment: use onchange function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//this shows the div
$(document).ready(function() {
  'use strict';
  $('#ae').on('keyup', function() {
    $('#ae-form').toggle(this.value.trim().toLowerCase() == 'allerganemployee');
    if(this.value.trim().toLowerCase() == 'allerganemployee'){
      $('#ae-input').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#ae-form {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="allergan box">
  <h2>Registration for Employees</h2>
  <div id="ae-input">
    <p>Please enter your password</p>
    <input type="password" id="ae" />
  </div>
  <div id="ae-form">
    This is the form
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the problem in my answer?

Comment: @PrateikDarji Every thing is okay with your answer except you are not hiding the label "Please enter your password"

Comment: perfect :-) thanx

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hiding on `keyup` event try to use `focusout` so that after entering password it will hide and use `delay(time_in_milliseconds)` function for delay.

```js
//this shows the div
$(document).ready(function() {
  'use strict';
  $('#ae').on('keyup', function() {
    $('#ae-form').toggle(this.value.trim().toLowerCase() == 'allerganemployee');
  });
});

var delay = function() {
  'use strict';
  $('#ae').on('focusout', function() {
    if(this.value.trim().toLowerCase() == 'allerganemployee'){
     $('#ae-input').delay(1000).hide();
 }
  });
};

//this needs to hide the input box  
$(document).ready(delay());
```

```css
#ae-form {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="allergan box">
  <h2>Registration for Employees</h2>
  <div id="ae-input">
    <p>Please enter your password</p>
    <input type="password" id="ae" />
  </div>
  <div id="ae-form">
    This is the form
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#ae-form').hide();
'use strict';
  $('#ae').on('change', function() {
    var a = this.value.trim().toLowerCase();
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      if(a == 'allerganemployee') {
        $('#ae-form').show();
        $('#ae').hide();
        $('#pwlabel').hide();
      } else {
        return;
      }
    }, 3000);
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="allergan box">
  <h2>Registration for Employees</h2>
  <div id="ae-input">
    <p id = "pwlabel">Please enter your password</p>
    <input type="password" id="ae" />
  </div>
  <div id="ae-form">
    This is the form
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//this shows the div
$(document).ready(function() {
  'use strict';
  $('#ae').on('keyup', function() {
    var check =  this.value.trim().toLowerCase() == 'allerganemployee';
    if(check){
     setTimeout(function() {
      $('#ae-input').hide();
      $('#ae-form').toggle(check);
     },1000);
    }
  });
});

//this needs to hide the input box  
$(document).ready(function() {
  'use strict';
  $('#ae').on('keyup', function() {
   
  });
});
```

```css
#ae-form {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="allergan box">
  <h2>Registration for Employees</h2>
  <div id="ae-input">
    <p>Please enter your password</p>
    <input type="password" id="ae" />
  </div>
  <div id="ae-form">
    This is the form
  </div>
</div>
```